# Does anyone know how to deploy Redis as cache along Postgres and Digital Ocean App for Django app?

Tags: django, caching, redis, digital-ocean

I deployed Django's app with Digital Ocean App service.  This is easy and quick without me having to deal with setting up a Ubuntu Droplet or anything like that for Django.  I also got Postgres as the main database for the Django app.  The problem is when I also set up Redis Managed Database as a cache server for my app, using VPC network connection such as rediss://private-location-on-digital-ocean:port# (also added the Django App and my own IP address as trusted source) - (also installed django-redis using pip) - to my chagrin I either got Internal Server Error or some vague error said that I have to check the log.  By the way I did update the requirements.txt to make sure all packages were installed for Redis to run properly with Django app.  Also, I set up the Redis as the CACHE backend in settings.py.  The only thing I see is that Postgres is being listed as a component for my Django app and Redis DB is not but it's using the same VPC that my Django app is using.  What could be the problem that I missed in order for me to get Redis to act as a cache server for my Django app on DO?  By the way, when I set up Redis on the local development server on my laptop, everything runs smoothly with exact same source code - but not so when I try to connect to managed Redis on DO.  So, any advice folks?

Answer (score 0):

A little late but, you can create users and databases by connecting to the digital ocean Postgres host.

`psql -h <IP_Address> -p <port_no> -d <database_name> -U <DB_username> -set=sslmode=require`

DO will give you the default DB and the default user along with the host(instead of an IP).

From there you can create a user, grant it permissions and give it a password.

Your settings file in the DB part will look a lot like this if you are using environment variables.

```
DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2",
        "NAME": os.environ.get('DATABASE_NAME'),
        "USER": os.environ.get('DATABASE_USERNAME'),
        "PASSWORD": os.environ.get('DATABASE_PASSWORD'),
        "HOST": os.environ.get('DATABASE_HOST'),
        "PORT": os.environ.get('DATABASE_PORT'),
    }
}
```

This [Tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-scalable-django-app-with-digitalocean-managed-databases-and-spaces) by DO pretty much shows how to go about the process.